# having issue with SOUPUI and WSDL in method response

Tags: php, wsdl, soapui

I am getting error as  "Function 'testMethod' doesn't exist"
in SOAP UI method response.
Method is there in php file as well as in WSDL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the answer...I missed to add object in SOAP class...it is done now